# OpenVPN: Routing all client traffic through the VPN - Do non-Windows clients require some extra server-side scripting?

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

**NB: I am a networking noob so please assume I know nothing and explain things accordingly (or provide links to more info).**

I am trying to set up an OpenVPN server such that all client traffic (including web-traffic) is routed through the VPN. I'm following the OpenVPN HOWTO and I've got as far as the "Routing all client traffic (including web-traffic) through the VPN" section (https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect).

My setup is:

- OpenVPN server (BeagleBone Black (BBB) on private network IP 10.240.233.2) connected to my broadband router at
  home (on private network IP 10.240.233.1).
- Client (laptop running Xubuntu GNU/Linux) connected to an external network.

I can successfully:

- Start OpenVPN server on the BBB on boot
- Connect client to VPN
- Ping OpenVPN server (10.8.0.1) from client (10.8.0.6) and *vice versa*
- Ping the router (10.240.233.1) from the client

The latter was achieved by:

- Adding the following directive to the server config file: `push "route 10.240.233.0 255.255.255.0"`
- Enabling IP forwarding on the OpenVPN server by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` (Here's the edit: `# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, after which the command `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` yields `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`)
- Enabling tun forwarding using the following commands (from this guide: https://nikinuryadin.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/step-by-step-setting-up-openvpn-in-debian-with-routing-tun-connection/): `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT` and `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT`

Now for the redirect bit...

I added the following directives to the server config file (from the OpenVPN HOWTO):

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.240.233.1"
```

NB: The pushed DNS IP is that of my broadband router, which I can successfully ping from the client when connected to the VPN and which the server is reporting as it's nameserver (`cat /etc/resolv.conf` on the server yields `nameserver 10.240.233.1`)

I then used the following command to NAT the VPN client traffic to the internet (from the OpenVPN HOWTO):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(Yes, my connection from the OpenVPN server to the broadband router is reported by the server as `eth0` (using `ifconfig`))

Finally, I did the following commands to save the iptables and restart the VPN (from the Niki Nuryadin linked above):

```
sudo iptables-save
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

I can successfully ping www.google.com and www.bbc.co.uk from the OpenVPN server. (I can also ping them from the laptop while not connected to the VPN, obv!). However, when connected to the VPN, I cannot ping those sites from the client.

Usually, if you try to ping something that's not available (e.g. `ping 192.168.7.2`), you get a result like this:

```
PING 192.168.7.2 (192.168.7.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and then it just hangs. However, in this case, when the client is connected to the OpenVPN server and I try to ping Google or BBC, I get no output at all.

I can't find the answer anywhere on serverfault.com or anywhere else. The only clue I have is that the OpenVPN HOWTO says:

> [Using `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.240.233.1"] will configure Windows clients (or non-Windows clients ***with some extra server-side scripting***) to use [10.240.233.1] as their DNS server.

So, do I need some extra server side scripting? Or is there some other problem?

Also, once I can ping websites and browse the internet, how can I check that all traffic is indeed going through the OpenVPN tunnel and not just bypassing it as it did before I took these steps?

Answer (score 0):

I have since found the answer. It was a typo in the HOWTO. The extra scripts are required on the *client* side, not the *server* side.

Simply add the following to the *client* conf file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

And to check that all traffic is going through the tunnel, use `traceroute`, e.g.

```
traceroute google.com
```

The output shows the route that packets take to get to the destination. You should see the VPN gateway (in my case, my broadband router at home) in the traceroute output.

Many thanks to the OpenVPN community forums for help with this: http://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=23249&p=67315&sid=f2657d061da760b5af60aec18dcea81e#p67315